# How to remove image from web root when data edit and update by cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, unlink

I write a edit function to update news's info, delete previous image from web root   and insert new image:

code is below:

```
       if(unlink($data['News']['image_url']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'media/' . $data['News']['image_url']['name'])) //delete image from root and database
            {
                echo 'image deleted.....';  //success message
            }
```

I can't delete old image and insert new image,how can i correct my function ?

Comment: `unlink($unsanitized` - bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here your data can not find existing data. use this code

```
$data1 = $this->News->findById($newsid);
$this->request->data = $data1;
$directory = WWW_ROOT . 'media';
if(unlink($directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$data1['News']['image_url']))  
{
    echo 'image deleted.....';  
}
```

Comment: Its best practice to check if file exist using http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php and then use unlink.

Answer (score 0):

Pass filepath as first argument of `unlink()`:

```
unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'media/' . $data['News']['image_url']['name'] . '/' . $data['News']['image_url']['tmp_name']);
```

Also make sure that you have proper permissions to perform this operation in directory containing image.